# ThreadSanitizer vs. async/await in XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, xctest

I'm trying to test an `async` function that creates a `WKWebsiteDataStore` with some `HTTPCookie`s.

```
import Foundation
import WebKit

@MainActor
class HttpCookieUtility {
    
    func createWebsiteDataStore(httpCookies: [HTTPCookie]) async -> WKWebsiteDataStore {

        let websiteDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistent()
        
        for cookie in httpCookies {
            await websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie)
        }
        
        return websiteDataStore
    }
}
```

The unit test code is here:

```
import XCTest
@testable import MyFramework

final class HttpCookieUtilityTests: XCTestCase {
    
    func test_websiteDataStore_is_created_from_cookies() async throws {
        
        var httpCookies = [HTTPCookie]()
        
        for index in 1...20 {
            
            let properties: [HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any] = [.domain: "www.example.com", .path: ".", .name: "name-\(index)", .value: "value-\(index)"]
            let httpCookie = HTTPCookie(properties: properties)!
            
            httpCookies.append(httpCookie)
        }
        
        let websiteDataStore = await HttpCookieUtility().createWebsiteDataStore(httpCookies: httpCookies)

        XCTAssertNotNil(websiteDataStore)
    }
}
```

The unit test passes. However, when I turn on the Thread Sanitizer in the scheme's Diagnostic settings, I see a series of warnings like the following (not all output include here for brevity):

> WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=47736)   Read of size 8 at
> 0x7b6400040310 by main thread:
> #0 (1) suspend resume partial function for HttpCookieUtilityTests.test_websiteDataStore_is_created_from_cookies()
> HttpCookieUtilityTests.swift:18 (MyFrameworkTests:x86_64+0x1e793)
> #1 swift::runJobInEstablishedExecutorContext(swift::Job*) :2 (libswift_Concurrency.dylib:x86_64+0x2a4b5)
>
> Previous write of size 8 at 0x7b6400040310 by thread T7:
> #0 HttpCookieUtilityTests.test_websiteDataStore_is_created_from_cookies()
> HttpCookieUtilityTests.swift:18 (MyFrameworkTests:x86_64+0x1e613)
> #1 swift::runJobInEstablishedExecutorContext(swift::Job*) :2 (libswift_Concurrency.dylib:x86_64+0x2a4b5)
>
> Location is heap block of size 1032 at 0x7b6400040100 allocated by
> thread T7:
> #0 malloc :2 (libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib:x86_64+0x533ac)
> #1 swift::StackAllocator<1000ul, &(swift::TaskAllocatorSlabMetadata)>::getSlabForAllocation(unsigned
> long) :2 (libswift_Concurrency.dylib:x86_64+0x2f19a)
> #2 swift::runJobInEstablishedExecutorContext(swift::Job*) :2 (libswift_Concurrency.dylib:x86_64+0x2a4b5)
>
> Thread T7 (tid=397262, running) is a GCD worker thread
>
> SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race HttpCookieUtilityTests.swift:18 in
> (1) suspend resume partial function for
> HttpCookieUtilityTests.test_websiteDataStore_is_created_from_cookies()

When I run the same code from a normal application, I don't see the same ThreadSanitizer warnings. I'm assuming that running XCTests that require the main thread are not supported or are somehow problematic. But I wanted to outrule issues with the actual code. I'm also just wondering if async/await is creating unexpected complications.

Also, I tried this alternate implementation which does not have the ThreadSanitizer issue, and is also significantly faster (presumably because the `setCookie` operations can process concurrently), but it specifically avoids using the modern concurrency support (aside from the `continuation`).

```
class HttpCookieUtility {

func createWebsiteDataStore(httpCookies: [HTTPCookie]) async -> WKWebsiteDataStore {

    return await withCheckedContinuation{ continuation in
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let websiteDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistent()

            let waitGroup = DispatchGroup()

            for cookie in httpCookies {
                waitGroup.enter()
                websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie, completionHandler: {
                    waitGroup.leave()
                })
            }

            waitGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
                continuation.resume(returning: websiteDataStore)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Note that I removed the `@MainActor` attribute from the `HttpCookieUtility` class declaration.

Comment: Try add `@MainActor` to your entire test class.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I tried suggestion: `@MainActor final class HttpCookieUtilityTests: XCTestCase`, but saw same warnings

Comment: FWIW, I created a blank project and added the above, turned on TSAN, and did not get these warnings...